# Could this use of "awhile" in a 1882 book be a mistake?

Tags: orthography

I found the following sentence in John Payne's translation of The Book of the Thousand Nights and One Night:

> So, when awhile of the night was past, he entered [...]

I think I understand the difference between "awhile" (adverb) and "a while" (noun phrase). It also seems to me that "awhile" tends to be more common in older (pre-20th century) texts than now. But I would say "awhile" does not fit in this case, as "*something* of the night" asks for a noun, not an adverb. Can I assume this is a mistake or misprint, or would this usage be acceptable in a book published in the 1880's and with an archaizing language (plenty of "thee" and "dost").

By the way, Burton's translation, uses "a while" in the same passage:

> Now when a while of the night was past, he entered [...]

Comment: Check the date: 1885.  This is an OED question and I don't have a subscription though they have a special rate this year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [*New English Dictionary*](https://archive.org/stream/oed01arch#page/595/mode/1up), later known as the *Oxford English Dictionary*, A–B (1889), terms this usage

> improperly written together, when there is no unification of sense and *while* is purely a sb. [substantive = noun].

The first example given for this usage is William Caxton’s *Faytes of Arms* (1489):

> It was doon but awhile agoon. *It was done but a while ago.*

“Improperly” written it may be, but in the 19th *awhile* — shall we call it a contraction? — commonly appears in a variety of genres.

> When this insect is first hatched, it bears a complete resemblance to a common mite, but after [*awhile*](https://books.google.de/books?id=TzcPAQAAIAAJ&pg=PP414&dq=%22after+awhile%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPs77RmsLbAhXF8ywKHfCkDoE4ZBDoAQg6MAQ) casts its skin, and undergoes a complete change. — *The British Encyclopedia* 6, 1809.
>
> Here Rifault was well received by the inhabitants, who were Tupinambas ; after [*awhile*](https://books.google.de/books?id=tNMTAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA392&dq=%22after+awhile%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPs77RmsLbAhXF8ywKHfCkDoE4ZBDoAQguMAI) he returned to Europe, leaving part - of his people under the command of Charles Sieur des Vaux. — Robert Southey, *History of Brazil, Part 1*,  1810, 392.
>
> The whigs after [*awhile*](https://books.google.de/books?id=m1VXYdFfeR8C&pg=PA238&dq=%22after+awhile%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje0728msLbAhVCVSwKHQCNAcs4WhDoAQgjMAA), cheerfully took the name ; but fastened on their adversaries in return an epithet altogether expressive of contempt ; ... — William Johnson, *Sketches of the Life and Correspondence of Nathanael Greene*,  1822.
>
> And when at times a thicker darkness has seemed to gather before them, men have recoiled as from an impassable barrier, and for [*awhile*](https://books.google.de/books?id=tM4s-N2F10oC&pg=PA107&dq=%22for+awhile%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGubDem8LbAhXDF5oKHT4OCVUQ6AEIMzAD) that path has been closed. But only for *awhile*.— *The Year-book of Facts in Science and the Arts for 1874*, 1875, 107.
>
> Heathenism was again for [*awhile*](https://books.google.de/books?id=xhtEAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA359&dq=%22for+awhile%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil0sK8nMLbAhVOyqYKHb1DBHA4FBDoAQgoMAE) restored after it had been rooted out. So much for the opposition of Satan against the success of the ... These heresies, which for *awhile* so much prevailed, after *awhile* dwindled away, and orthodoxy was again restored. — Jonathan Edwards,  *Dissertation of the End for which God Created the World*,  1829.

A [Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=after%20awhile%2Cafter%20a%20while&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cafter%20awhile%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cafter%20a%20while%3B%2Cc0) suggests that this alternate was never more frequent than what the NED would consider “proper” English.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Given the number of times that "awhile" occurs in the book ([here](https://books.google.com/books?id=z45FAQAAIAAJ&q=%22awhile%22#v=snippet&q=%22awhile%22&f=false) is a search for it an the 1884 edition), I don't think it was misprint. However, it certainly seems like using "awhile" instead of the article + noun "a while" has always been considered nonstandard.

---

Here's what the Oxford English Dictionary has to say about this sense of *awhile*:

> Improperly written together, when there is no unification of sense, and *while* is purely a noun.

It gives one example from [1489](https://books.google.com/books?id=l7tZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22It+was+doon%22+%22awhyle%22&dq=%22It+was+doon%22+%22awhyle%22&hl=en), another from [1872](https://books.google.com/books?id=qL5JAAAAIAAJ&pg=RA2-PA102&lpg=RA2-PA102&dq=%22For+awhile+the+facilities%22%22enabled+the+Venetians%22), and a third from [1882](https://books.google.com/books?id=XgErAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=%22After+awhile+they+seemed+to+pacify+each+other.%22).

---

I was also able to find a [grammar book](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZWUVAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA242&dq=grammar+%22awhile%22+%22a+while%22) from 1889 which "improves" the following "bad construction":

> [T]here was also a beach where we went bathing every once and awhile.

to the "improved":

> [B]esides, there was a fine beach from which we went in bathing every once in a while.